# Connecting a router to a private network

Tags: networking, wireless-router, hotspot

I want to use a router to my hostel network so that I can connect to internet using Wifi. I heard that doing that will cause some Ip clashes and all. How is it possible?. Suppose I share the net using a hotspot application, will that create any problems to main network?

Comment: Are you asking as the network administrator, or as a visitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hot spot application wont be problem because they will share your internet and using your ip

but the router doesn't use one ip it gives each client ip address as it is in your main DHCP server (like your main router ) hear is an image that show my purpose

http://wiki.slimdevices.com/uploads/a/ae/Network_diagram_WAP.jpg

router give clients (network valid ip) but hot spot apps share your ip

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wireless router with very little to no problems if you follow the following best practices:

1. Use authentication, i.e: [WPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access). This is usually created during the initial setup of your router. This ensures that only people who have the correct password/credentials will access the network.
2. Choose a private network range that is appropriate to the number of users you expect on your network. A /24 network (netmask = 255.255.255.0) can accommodate up to 253 users simultaneously, given you only have the router and end users (no other devices, i.e: printers). This will ensure that everyone can connect at the same time.
3. Choose a router that can cover the whole perimeter. Depending on the building size, different routers can be appropriate. See this article for more information: [Which Wireless Router Has the Best Range?](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wirelessrouters/f/bestwifirange.htm)
4. You should also make sure that the router is capable of processing all of the bandwidth that will be supplied to it. For example, if you have a 100 Mbps network connection then use a 150 Mbps router, not a 54 Mbps one.

If one router is not enough to cover the whole building, you can choose one of the following options:

1. Use a [wireless extender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater).
2. Get another wired connection, and connect a second router. **Make sure the private network ranges are different**.
3. Use multiple wireless access points with a wireless network controller. Employing this method usually requires advanced, specialized knowledge, and is usually expensive. [Cisco Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Systems) offers one such solution, called the [Wireless LAN Controller](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/wireless-lan-controller/index.html).

You can also make use of hotspot managing software. Some routers come with this functionality built in, like [MikroTik](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/wireless-lan-controller/index.html) routers. If your router doesn't, you can use a separate server to manage the hotspot. Usually, any PC could act as that server, depending on the particular software you're using.